# Markdown in Azure Pipelines Summary File

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a task in my pipeline that uploads some markdown with a summary

```
##vso[task.uploadsummary]c:\testsummary.md
```

The markdown looks like this

```
Summary
======
- Created resources: 0
- Deleted resources: 0
- Updated resources: 0
- Unchanged resources: 117
- Skipped resources: 1

Details
======
- Skipped detail
  - MSGraph/DeviceAppManagement/MobileApps:
    - AnyDesk
```

All this works fine but the Extensions tab with the markdown that shows up on my build summary does not correctly render my markdown with the indented/nested lists. All the bullets are at the same level. Is this just a bug in the DevOps markdown rendering? Or is there a way to work around?

[image]

Also, is there any way to get DevOps to include this summary in the notification email that gets sent out after the build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange. I followed you and I got the same result. Additionally I created a file in Azure DevOps Wiki which was displayed in this way there:

[image]

I copied a content of this file to create it during pipeline and uplod it using logging command. It was displayed in that way there:

[image]

But I also published this file and download to my machine and I got this:
[image]

In my opinion this is something for [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).